# Can I password-lock a CD-R after being burned?

Tags: disk-encryption, password-protection, cd

I've been trying to find a program that could let me password lock or encrypt a CD-R I burned 10 years ago. I do not remember what program I used to burn it. Would it still be possible to modify the disc's empty space to password protect it?

I thought I could try using Bitlocker to lock access to the CD but apparently it doesn't work with optical media. Is there any other method or program that could help?

Comment: Wouldn't it be far easier to re-record the CD again (and destroy the current copy you have) and encrypt the content prior to recording it? For example, you can encrypt the content with 7-zip archiver and record such an archive.

Comment: It would but I wanted to know if I could keep the CD itself as historical reference while also making the data secure.

Answer (score 2):

There would be little point in doing this.  The unencrypted information would still be accessible.

The correct solution might by to copy the disk into a veracrypt container file, then master and burn a new iso including the veracrypt file and optionally a copy of Veracrypt, and then destroy the old disk.

You talk about 10 year time frames - while in practice DVSs are often OK for that period of time, you should not rely on them for that long - if the data is valuable, burn more then 1 copy (using different brands of media) and ideally a different media as well.

Comment: "burn more then 1 copy (...) and ideally a different media as well" -- and if your data leaves any room on the media then add some redundancy with (e.g.) [`parchive`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive).